# MongoDB - Node.js -- $or operation on $match aggregator returning "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to do the following using the native mongodb drive for Node.js:

```
db.collection('myColec').aggregate([
        {
            $match:{
                /*$or:[{name:"adam"},{channel:"steve"}]*/
                'name': {$in: ['adam','steve']}
                     },
            $group: {
                //_id: "$notes",
                _id: {channel: "$name",name:"$age"},
                earnings: {$sum: "$earnings"},
                years: {$sum: "$years"},
                years: {$sum: "$years"}
            }   
       }],
function(err,res){
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    //do something
}
```

According to this documentation:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match

I should be able to accomplish something like this.

Comment: what mongo client are you using?

Comment: I think you just have to wrap the $match in quotes like so "$match":

Comment: I am using the mongodb module for node.js.

Comment: wrapping the $match in quotes returned the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass array of objects. Each object there describes one operation ($match, $group etc). But you pass array with only one object. And this object contains multiple fields. It is incorrect.

So try to write your query like this:

```
db.collection('myColec').aggregate(
        [{
          $match:
                /*$or:[{name:"adam"},{channel:"steve"}]*/
                'name': {$in: ['adam','steve']}

        },
        { 
          $group: {
                //_id: "$notes",
                _id: {channel: "$name",name:"$age"},
                earnings: {$sum: "$earnings"},
                years: {$sum: "$years"},
                years: {$sum: "$years"}

        }],
function(err,res){
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    //do something
})
```

**UPD:**
Also you can pass these object as separate arguments. It is not required to wrap them in array. One more example:

```
db.collection('myColec').aggregate(
        {
          $match:
                /*$or:[{name:"adam"},{channel:"steve"}]*/
                'name': {$in: ['adam','steve']}

        },
        { 
          $group: {
                //_id: "$notes",
                _id: {channel: "$name",name:"$age"},
                earnings: {$sum: "$earnings"},
                years: {$sum: "$years"},
                years: {$sum: "$years"}

        },
function(err,res){
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    //do something
})
```

Check out the docs. It is very helpful and contains a lot of examples: [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#aggregate)

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up not needing to pass an array I will post my answer.

Comment: Yes. It is also possible to pass these objects as separate arguments. It is not required to wrap them in array.

Answer (score 0):

My code ended up being the below - for some reason I did not have to pass an array.

```
db.collection('myColec').aggregate(
   {$match:{'name':{$in:['adam','steve']}}},

    {$group: {
            _id: {age:"$age"},
            earnings: {$sum: "$earnings"},
            views: {$sum: "$years"},
            adViews: {$sum: "$years"}
        }   
    }, function(err,res){
        //do something
    })
```